# Incomplete Pioneer 3-AT URDF

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I seem to be having a slight issue, whereby the Pioneer 3-AT doesn't seem to produce a complete RobotModel. I am currently using the p2os_urdf package to initiate this RobotModel. Even initiating the launch file for a pioneer3dx seem to produce the same issue..

Any help would be very much appreciated!

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66333/incomplete-pioneer-3-at-urdf/) by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What graphic card are you using? I had some problems with visualization in RVIZ with Intel (integrated) card. Then, with NVIDIA, it was fine.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on 2013-07-01**:
Im using a Lenovo G480 with both integrated Intel and NVIDIA graphic card. Oh so it could be a driver issue? Because I did have some problem with most of the drivers when first installing Ubuntu 12.04..

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-07-01**:
On my notebook it was necessary to switch off NVIDIA Optimus in BIOS and use dedicated graphic card all the time. Optimus is not well supported in Linux (you can try Bumblebee driver/utility).

**Comment by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on 2013-07-16**:
I've actually tried the package with another laptop and the robot model's perfect! Must have been the drivers of my graphic card..may have had some problem earlier. Thanks!